# CakePHP Unit Testing testAction throws: Undefined index SERVER_PORT

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.6

We've got PHPUnit testing setup in our CakePHP 2.6.x application, but everytime the example test is run testAction throws this error:

```
UsersControllerTest::testLogin
Undefined index: SERVER_PORT
```

For this unit test:

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $result = $this->testAction( '/users/login' );

    ...

    debug( $result );
}
```

Anyone know what has been missed?  There isn't any mention of SERVER_PORT in the docs under testing.

Answer (score 0):

Some component (from CakePHP or yours) is making use of this property, and it's not being set when running from CLI.

You can set it manually in the setUp method of the failing test.